# C++ - deduce parameter pack (variadic template) constructor and copy constructor by enable_if_t

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, variadic

Update:
Thank you, Jamboree.
This is the final `struct A`.

```
struct A
{
    template<class ... Args,class=std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args)!=1)>>
    A(Args &&...args)
    {
        cout<<'v';
    }
    template<class Arg,class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<std::remove_reference_t<Arg>,A>::value>>
    A(Arg &&arg)
    {
        cout<<'v';
    }
    A(const A &)
    {
        cout<<'c';
    }
    A(A &&)
    {
        cout<<'m';
    }
};
```

Origin:
About this code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    template<class ... Args,class=std::enable_if_t<
        sizeof...(Args)!=1
        ||!std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>>,A>::value>>
    A(Args &&...args)
    {
        cout<<'v';
    }
    A(const A &)
    {
        cout<<'c';
    }
    A(A &&)
    {
        cout<<'m';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a{10};
    A b{10,20};
    A c{b};
    const A d{c};
    A e{move(c)};
}
```

The output is `vvvvm` in VC++ 14.0.
But why is the output not `vvccm`?
(I want `c and d` to use copy constructor. And I know Effective Modern C++ Item 27 use only one forwarding reference.)

Comment: This should be ill-formed for using `Args` unexpanded.

Comment: But if I use `std::remove_reference_t<Args...>`, it occurs compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `b` and `c`, is `A&` to the compiler (not const-qualified) when you pass them to the ctor of `c` and `d`, `Args &&...args` is thus a better match than `const A &`.

To achieve what you want, you could do it this way:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;

    template<class ... Args,std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args)>1), bool> = true>
    A(Args &&...args)
    {
        cout<<'v';
    }

    template<class Arg,std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<A, std::remove_reference_t<Arg>>::value, bool> = true>
    A(Arg && arg)
    {
        cout<<'v';
    }

    A(const A &)
    {
        cout<<'c';
    }
    A(A &&)
    {
        cout<<'m';
    }
};
```

Comment: In this example, a default constructor is always needed. If not specified explicitly, make sure to write `sizeof...(Args)!=1` instead